# Json Menu Structure from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have been going round and round with this issue, seemed very simple. I am trying to produce a menu/submenu json out put with PHP/MYSQL: These are the tables:

```
   CREATE TABLE `menuHome` 
  `id`,
  `titleName`

   CREATE TABLE `menu` 
  `id`,
  `parentmenu`,
  `name`
```

'menuHome' would have 'titleName' such as 'About Us' joined by 'id' on 'menu' by 'parentmenu' this would have multiple entries such as 'history', 'Owners', 'News'.

The structure I am trying to achieve is:

```
`
 {
  "menu" : {
    "sections" : [
      {
        "title" : "About Us",
        "items" : [
          {
            "name" : "History",
            "id" : "0909"
          },
          {
            "name" : "Owners",
            "id" : "0910"
          },
          {
            "name" : "News",
            "id" : "0916"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title" : "Contact Us",
        "items" : [
          {
            "name" : "Address",
            "id" : "0949"
          },
          {
            "name" : "Map",
            "id" : "0978"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title" : "Products",
        "items" : [
          {
            "name" : "Jeans",
            "id" : "1010"
          },
          {
            "name" : "Tables",
            "id" : "1088"
          },
          {
            "name" : "Shoes",
            "id" : "2424"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}


`
```

I have tried, while, for, for each in lots of configurations but I can not make it build the right array structure to encode to json. I am now at the code blindness stage so any help would be greatly received

this was my last attempt:

```
     $sql_query  = 'SELECT menuHome.titleName, menuHome.id FROM menuHome';
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);
        $menu = array();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $menuid = $row["id"];

        $sql_query2  = 'SELECT menu.name, menu.id FROM menu WHERE menu.parentmenu = "' .  $menuid . '"';

        $result2 = $mysqli->query($sql_query2);

        while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

         $menu[$row["titleName"]][] = $row2;


         }
        }

return json_encode($menu);
```

This is the result the above brings:

```
{
  "About Us" : [
    {
      "name" : "History",
      "id" : "1"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Owners",
      "id" : "2"
    },
    {
      "name" : "News",
      "id" : "3"
    }
  ],
  "Contact Us" : [
    {
      "name" : "Address",
      "id" : "4"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Map",
      "id" : "5"
    }
  ],
  "Products" : [
    {
      "name" : "Jeans",
      "id" : "6"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Tables",
      "id" : "7"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Shoes",
      "id" : "8"
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is I can not get the 'pairs' prior - "title" = "About us"...it's something simple but I am brain dead over this issue.

I can add this before json_encode:

```
  $menuoutput = array("menu" => array("sections" => array($menu)));
```

But how do I get the 'key' 'titleName' or just 'title' to display before 'About Us'...

Comment: show what have you tried

Comment: don't forget that you can build it as php `array` and then use `json_encode()` to convert it to json string.

Comment: please display what output are you getting after json_encode, say with a `var_dump(json_encode($menu))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First off I assume your data goes like this -

> INSERT INTO `menu` 
>   (`id`, `parentmenu`, `name`) 
>   VALUES 
>   (1,1,"history"), 
>   (2,1,"owners"), 
>   (3,1,"news"), 
>   (4,2,"address"), 
>   (5,2,"map"), 
>   (6,3,"jeans"), 
>   (7,3,"tables"), 
>   (8,3,"shoes");

> INSERT INTO menuHome 
>   (`id`,`titleName`) 
>   VALUES 
>   (1,"About Us"), 
>  
>   (2,"Contact Us"), 
>   (3,"Products");

- secondly i will suggest you to change your query to -

> SELECT pm.id, cm.id, pm.titleName, cm.name FROM menu as cm 
>   LEFT JOIN (menuHome as pm) 
>  
>   ON (pm.id = cm.parentmenu);

- third, lets get to coding

for our purposes we want something like this -

> $arys = ["menu"=>["sections" => [ 
>   ["title" => "About Us", "items" => [
>                                                                           ["name"=>"History","id"=>1],
>                                                                           ["name"=>"Owners","id"=>2],
>                                                                           ["name"=>"News","id"=>3]
>   ]],
>   ["title" => "Contact Us", "items" => [
>   ["name"=>"Address","id"=>4],
>   ["name"=>"Map","id"=>5]
>   ]],
>   ["title" => "Products", "items" => [
>   ["name"=>"Jeans","id"=>6],
>   ["name"=>"Tables","id"=>7],
>   ["name"=>"Shoes","id"=>8]
>   ]]
>   ]
>   ]
>   ];

So let's build it up

> $querys = "Select pm.id AS pmd , cm.id AS cmd, pm.titleName AS pmt, cm.name AS cmt from menu as cm left join (menuHome as pm) on (pm.id = cm.parentmenu) Order By pmd, cmd "; 
>   $result = mysql_query($querys); 
>   $jsary = ["menu" => ["sections" => []]]; 
>   $lastPid = 0; 
>   $currentPid = 0; 
>   $title = ""; 
>   $ifff = 0; 
>   $elss = 0; 
>   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
>   {
>           $currentPid = $row['pmd'];
>           $title = $row['pmt'];

```
    $cmd = $row['cmd'];
    $cmt = $row['cmt'];

    if($lastPid != $currentPid)
    {
            $insAry = [];
            $insAry = ["title"=> $title, "items" => [["name" => $cmt, "id" => $cmd]]];
            array_push($jsary["menu"]["sections"], $insAry);
            $lastPid = $currentPid;
            $ifff = $ifff + 1;
            $currentPid = 0;
    }
    else
    {
            $ind = 0;
            if($ifff > 0)
            {
                    $ind = $ifff-1;
            }
            $insAry = [];
            $insAry = ["name" => $cmt, "id" => $cmd];
            array_push($jsary["menu"]["sections"][$ind]["items"], $insAry);
    }}
```

Now just call json_encode()

> json_encode($jsary);

You'll have your desired output

Comment: Also, you don't need to use two Tables to hold Parent Menu Item in one and Child Menu Item in another, since both represent same type of data element, simply modify your table like
- Table menu ( menu_id, parent_menu_id, title )

Comment: Thank you Joddy, good to know I still have much to learn. Why use 20 lines when only 40 do the job. Thanks again, I will sleep tonight.

Comment: Hi, it'll be great if you can mark the question as answered and close it.
And, I'm glad I was of some help ;)