# need to get json format from php

Tags: php, json

**I am getting a json format like this**

```
[{"service":{"title":"karthik","city":"chennai"}},{"service":{"title":"siva","city":"madurai"}}]
```

**from code**

```
$rt = array();
$rt["service"]["title"] = karthik;
$rt["service"]["city"] = chennai;

$t = array();
$t["service"]["title"] = siva;
$t["service"]["city"] = madurai;

echo json_encode(array($rt,$t));
```

**but i need the same format of json result from  this code**

```
$a=mysql_query("SELECT  title,city,category,parentid,pay,task.id 
FROM task");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($a))
{
$jsonrow=new stdClass;
$jsonrow->title=$row['title'];
$jsonrow->city=$row['city'];


$jsonresponse=new stdClass;
$jsonresponse->service=$jsonrow;

}

echo json_encode(array($jsonresponse));
```

**but the result actually i get from the above code is**

```
[{"service":{"title":"Event Help","city":"Santa Fe"}}]
```

please someone help me on this issue.....

Comment: what is wrong here ? both json looks same

Comment: i need a result like this [{"service":{"title":"karthik","city":"chennai"}},{"service":{"title":"siva","city":"madurai"}}]

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156159/json-menu-structure-from-mysql/13157562#13157562

And re-think

Comment: what you exactly getting in `echo json_encode(array($jsonresponse));` ?

Comment: thanks for your info let me try

Comment: [{"service":{"title":"Event Help","city":"Santa Fe"}}] this what i get from echo json_encode(array($jsonresponse)); @GBD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array store all the values returned from the query

```
$array = array();
$a=mysql_query("SELECT  title,city,category,parentid,pay,task.id 
FROM task");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($a))
{
  $jsonrow=new stdClass;
  $jsonrow->title=$row['title'];
  $jsonrow->city=$row['city'];


  $jsonresponse=new stdClass;
  $jsonresponse->service=$jsonrow;
  $array[] = $jsonresponse;
}

echo json_encode(array($array));
```

Answer (score 1):

you are overwriting `$jsonresponse` in your while loop, you should add this into array and `json_encode` this array

```
$response = array();

while( ... ){
    ...
    $response[] = $jsonresponse;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
  $a=mysql_query("SELECT  title,city,category,parentid,pay,task.id  FROM
  task");

  $jsonrow=new stdClass;
  $jsonresponse=new stdClass;
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($a)) {

  $jsonrow->title=$row['title']; $jsonrow->city=$row['city'];    
  $jsonresponse->service=$jsonrow;

   }
```