# Combine Rows for Json Encode

Tags: php, mysql, merge, json

I am having trouble merging data before outputting json. The goal is to have each object in the json to contain all the data for each 'post'.

The below code:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT dfuw_posts.ID, dfuw_posts.post_title,
dfuw_postmeta.meta_key, dfuw_postmeta.post_id, dfuw_postmeta.meta_value FROM
dfuw_posts INNER JOIN dfuw_postmeta ON dfuw_posts.ID = dfuw_postmeta.post_id WHERE
dfuw_posts.post_type = 'poi' AND dfuw_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND 
dfuw_postmeta.meta_key IN ('_poi_loc' ,'_poi_level' ,'_poi_type')");

$pois = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
  $pois[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($pois);
```

Outputs:

```
[
 {
  "ID": "320",
  "post_title": "Bank",
  "meta_key": "_poi_loc",
  "post_id": "320",
  "meta_value": "70.4845662217412|-84.5123291015625"
 },
 {
  "ID": "320",
  "post_title": "Bank",
  "meta_key": "_poi_level",
  "post_id": "320",
  "meta_value": "easy"
 },
 {
  "ID": "320",
  "post_title": "Bank",
  "meta_key": "_poi_type",
  "post_id": "320",
  "meta_value": "bank"
 },
 {
  "ID": "324",
  "post_title": "A Creature",
  "meta_key": "_poi_type",
  "post_id": "324",
  "meta_value": "mob"
 },
 {
  "ID": "324",
  "post_title": "A Creature",
  "meta_key": "_poi_level",
  "post_id": "324",
  "meta_value": "med"
 },
 {
  "ID": "324",
  "post_title": "A Creature",
  "meta_key": "_poi_loc",
  "post_id": "324",
  "meta_value": "70.4845662217412|-84.5123291015625"
 }
]
```

I would like for each post to be bundled like:

```
{
  "title": "A Creature",
  "location": "70.4845662217412|-84.5123291015625",
  "type": "mob",
  "level": "hard"
 }
```

Is this achievable? If so, any suggestions to send me on the right path would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156159/json-menu-structure-from-mysql/13157562#13157562

Comment: @Joddy, thanks! Will look into this. This looks like what I am trying to achieve. Will try once I step away and get some sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is what I ended up solving my issue with.

```
$results = mysql_query("
     SELECT
        dfuw_posts.ID AS pid,
        dfuw_posts.post_title AS title,
        dfuw_postmeta.meta_key AS mkey,
        dfuw_postmeta.post_id AS pmid,
        dfuw_postmeta.meta_value AS mval
     FROM
        dfuw_posts
     INNER JOIN
        dfuw_postmeta ON dfuw_posts.ID = dfuw_postmeta.post_id
     WHERE
        dfuw_posts.post_type = 'poi'
     AND
        dfuw_posts.post_status = 'publish'
     AND
        dfuw_postmeta.meta_key IN ('_poi_loc' ,'_poi_level' ,'_poi_type')");

  $jsary = ["pois" => []];
  $lastPid = 0;
  $currentPid = 0;
  $title = "";
  $ifff = 0;
  $elss = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
    {
        $currentPid = $row['pid'];
        $title = $row['title'];

        $cmd = $row['mkey'];
        $cmt = $row['mval'];

        if($lastPid != $currentPid)
        {
                $insAry = [];
                $insAry = ["title"=> $title, $cmd => $cmt];
                array_push($jsary["pois"], $insAry);
                $lastPid = $currentPid;
                $ifff = $ifff + 1;
                $currentPid = 0;
        }
        else
        {
                $ind = 0;
                if($ifff > 0)
                {
                        $ind = $ifff-1;
                }
                $insAry = [$cmd => $cmt];
                $jsary["pois"][$ind][$cmd] = $cmt;
        }
      }

echo json_encode($jsary);
```

This outputs the data beautifully as:

```
{
 "pois": [
 {
   "title": "Bank",
   "_poi_loc": "70.4845662217412|-84.5123291015625",
   "_poi_level": "easy",
   "_poi_type": "bank"
 },
 {
   "title": "A Creature",
   "_poi_type": "mob",
   "_poi_level": "med",
   "_poi_loc": "70.4845662217412|-84.5123291015625"
 }
]
```

Thanks for all the replies. @Joddy - your post helped me to get where I ended up. TY!

Answer (score 0):

Giving custom title in mysql query will solve your problem.

```
$results = mysql_query("
         SELECT 
            dfuw_posts.ID,
            dfuw_posts.post_title AS title,
            dfuw_postmeta.meta_key,
            dfuw_postmeta.post_id,
            dfuw_postmeta.meta_value AS location
         FROM
            dfuw_posts
         INNER JOIN 
            dfuw_postmeta ON dfuw_posts.ID = dfuw_postmeta.post_id 
         WHERE
            dfuw_posts.post_type = 'poi'
         AND
            dfuw_posts.post_status = 'publish'
         AND 
            dfuw_postmeta.meta_key IN ('_poi_loc' ,'_poi_level' ,'_poi_type')");

$pois = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
  $pois[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($pois);
```

Try and post what you ended up in.

Comment: that actually does help, but I am still getting 3 separate rows for 1 item. The issue is the `(dfuw_postmeta.meta_key IN ('_poi_loc' ,'_poi_level' ,'_poi_type')` makes the query return 3 rows for 1 item, instead of all 3 meta_keys in one row.

Comment: have you try to concat them.? hope group by also work or try left outer join so it will not repeat if its could not find any association in second table.

Comment: I have tried concat, but I would need the group fields to be in an nested object. Which is my main issue. In my initial output, notice the first 3 objects have the same ID. I am trying to merge those 3 to all be in one object.